# set two different memory stores for one dojo widget (dijit/form/FilteringSelect) at the same time

Tags: dojo

I have two different JSON structures. One represent the individual users of the system and other represents groups made of these users. So, I created two memory  stores with these (each has different idProperty - userId and groupId, respectively).

I have a filteringSelect dropdown and my requirement is to add both of these as the data store of the list, so that either a valid user or a valid group could be selected from the dropdown.

Two possible ways I could think of doing this :
1) by creating one common memory store of two JSONs - but idProperty is different so not sure how this is possible
2) by adding both the memory stores to the widget but again different idProperty so not sure.

I am very new to using Dojo so any help would be really appreaciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, if you use a store to represent something (model data), it should be formed so that it can be used properly within a widget.

So in your case I would add both of them to a single store. If they have a different ID (for example when it's a result of a back-end service), then you could map both types of models into a single object structure. For example:

```js
var groups = [{
    groupId: 1,
    groupName: "Group 1",
    users: 10
}, {
    groupId: 2,
    groupName : "Group 2",
    users: 13
}, {
    groupId: 3,
    groupName : "Group 3",
    users: 2
}];

var users = [{
    userId: 1,
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
}, {
    userId: 2,
    firstName: "Jane",
    lastName: "Doe"
}, {
    userId: 3,
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Smith"
}];


require(["dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Memory, FilteringSelect, array) {
    var filterData = array.map(groups, function(group) {
        return {
            id: "GROUP" + group.groupId,
            groupId: group.groupId,
            name: group.groupName,
            type: "group"
        };
    });
    Array.prototype.push.apply(filterData, array.map(users, function(user) {
        return {
            id: "USER" + user.userId,
            userId: user.userId,
            name: user.firstName + " " + user.lastName,
            type: "user"
        };
    }));
});
```

In this example, we have two arrays `groups` and `users`, and to merge them I used the `map()` function of `dojo/_base/array` and then I concatenated both results.

They still contain their original ID and a type, so you will still be able to reference the original object.

From my previous experiences, I learned that your model data should not represent pure business data, but data that is easily used in the view/user interface.

By giving both arrays a similar object structure, you can easily use them in a `dijit/form/FilteringSelect`, which you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ut5hjbyb/